# How to solve this limit with e power in both numerator and denominator?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cvda.png)

This limit gives result of $\frac{1}{2}$ by Wolfram Alpha. I have searched that we should use Taylor expansion to expand the e, but I got 1 eventually. Very thankful if there is any answer!